# Google caching random pages in foreign language

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

I maintain a react-laravel website.

Google has been caching some random pages which should not be in first place. Moreover, they look like eCommerce pages of someone else.

Check this cached page link `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1tS6wPyBv0AJ:amitkk.com/it+&cd=53&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in`

Also, you can see a lot of Japanese urls in `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aamitkk.com&rlz=1C1SQJL_enIN819IN819&oq=site&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j69i65l3.2895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8`

My website has no Japanese connection of any kind and still this is coming up.

Can anyone, advice on how to remove this and how did it happen too.

Answer (score 1):

When Google has indexed and cached unexpected foreign language pages from your site, it is almost always a sign that your site has been hacked.  Somebody hacked into your server and and created foreign language content on your domain.

The hackers may prevent you from seeing the hacked content, while showing it to Google.  This makes it harder for you to find and clean up the hack while allowing them to get the search engine boost from the hack that they are working towards.

[Google maintains a guide for helping you deal with a hacked site](https://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/?hl=en).  Go there and figure out how to clean it up.